# Algolia InstantSearch default Parameters / Scope

Tags: reactjs, algolia

I have a React app that is using the Algoia InstantSearch library.  This one https://community.algolia.com/react-instantsearch/

```
  <InstantSearch
    appId="KJH78673IUH"
    apiKey="e55e048w7fh8wh8wrgh834c3ea51e3"
    indexName="Events"
  >
    <Configure hitsPerPage={10} />
    <SearchBox />
    <h3>Latest Events</h3>
    <Hits />
    <Index indexName="Venues">
      <h3>Latest Venues</h3>
      <Hits />
    </Index>
    <Index indexName="Users">
      <h3>Latest Users</h3>
      <Hits />
    </Index>
  </InstantSearch>
```

This works fine and pulls the results as I type.  However.  On each of the Event, Venue and User records I have an attribute `site_id`.  I am struggle to figure out how I can set the `site_id` to be like a default scope on the search query.  Along the lines of how `default_scope` works in Rails.  I am sure this is possible but failing to figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Check [this](https://community.algolia.com/react-instantsearch/guide/Search_state.html) out.

Comment: Thanks for that.   I still dont quite get it...sorry.  I have tried adding a <Configure site_id='1' /> but it does not recognise the key.

Comment: I tried to replicate the issue on codesandbox, but it seems that your app id is wrong.

Comment: @bobylito I changed those details just because I didn't want it exposed to the public.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this using VirtualWidgets.

https://community.algolia.com/react-instantsearch/connectors/connectMenu.html

The scope an index to a particular attribute I used the following method:

```
import { connectMenu } from 'react-instantsearch/connectors';
const VirtualMenu = connectMenu(() => null);
// RESET OF COMPONENT CODE
<InstantSearch
    appId="KJH78673IUH"
    apiKey="e55e048w7fh8wh8wrgh834c3ea51e3"
    indexName="Events"
  />
    <Configure hitsPerPage={10} />
    <VirtualMenu attribute="site_id" defaultRefinement="1" />
    <SearchBox />
    <h3>Latest Events</h3>
    <Hits />
    <Index indexName="Venues">
      <h3>Latest Venues</h3>
      <Hits />
    </Index>
    <Index indexName="Users">
      <h3>Latest Users</h3>
      <Hits />
    </Index>
  </InstantSearch>
```

You can also add the VirtualWidget to the `Index` block itself too.